# How to add title to all id's with jquery

Tags: jquery, title

How to add titles to all id's for td in table.

Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="A">TextA</td>
        <td id="A">TextB</td>
        <td id="A">TextC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('#A')[0].title = "new title value";
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3hocugmj/

I have try with for loop like this:

```
for (b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
    $('#A')[b].title = "new title value";
}
```

But this is not working... any ideas how to solve this?

Realy thanks.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you cannot have elements with the same `id` in the same page. Use a class instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid - you cannot have elements with the same `id` in the same page. Use a class instead

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">TextA</td>
        <td class="A">TextB</td>
        <td class="A">TextC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then your JS becomes a one-liner (assuming you want all elements to have the same `title` attribute):

```
$('.A').prop('title', 'new title value');
```

If they need different values, you can give `prop()` a function containing the logic to set the title:

```
$('.A').prop('title', function() {
    return 'new title value: ' + $(this).text();
});
```

The above would result in the following values:

```
new title value: TextA
new title value: TextB
new title value: TextC
```

Comment: thanks it works, you are the best :) sorry because of question, I am a begginer at jquery